# Выборка из двух таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две таблицы из которых нужно выбрать поля которые не имеют общих записей и не связаны между собой, делаю так

```
SELECT menu.url,menu_deyatelnost.alias 
FROM menu,menu_deyatelnost WHERE
 menu.url!=''
```

В результате 5 раз дублируются записи

Answer (score 1):

Это называется декартово произведение. не делайте так. сделайте два отдельных запроса.

Comment: так и сделал UNION